# What happened with some users reputation today?

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, down-votes

Today something weird happened to my account, I got [4 downvotes on questions in less than 2 minutes.](https://superuser.com/users/79358/diogo?tab=reputation)

I thought it had just happened to me, but, when requesting for moderator help on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4829707#4829707), I saw that user [Luke](https://superuser.com/users/24010/luke?tab=reputation) had the same problem too. So, I just researched on [another users](https://superuser.com/users) and I found out that another users had exactly the same problem as me and Luke, such as [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck?tab=reputation), [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab?tab=reputation) and [techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007?tab=reputation)

As you can see, all of them just happened about the same time. So, there was a bug from system? Some angry user mass downvoted everyone or something? Could some moderator check this?

> Note: To be exact, the downvotes all occurred around **18:25 UTC**.

---

*(screenshots for evidence)*

**Diogo (Me):**

[image: diogo]

**Luke:**

[image: luke]

**slhck:**

[image: slhck]

**Moab:**

[image: moab]

**techie007:**

[image: techie007]

Comment: Heh, reached the rep cap even though I got serial downvotes? Nice :P

Comment: Aww. Now I feel left out. :( lol

Comment: Let's wait until tomorrow. This should be reversed automatically.

Comment: On my opinion it looks like an angry user... and not a system bug, in this case I would expect serial downvotes everyday until all my questions were downvoted..

Comment: I think Tom was hit, too: http://superuser.com/users/9666/tom-wijsman?tab=reputation

Comment: @igvzx Yes, it looks like...

Comment: I know that moderators have no access to who downvoted or upvoted questions, but there is someone, maybe a "supermoderator" here that could?

Comment: Checking this out.

Comment: Neat, I just noticed that it happened to me so I figured I'd come see if anyone else got hit.. Low and behold you guys are ON IT.  At least I don't feel so bad now.. misery loves company 'n all. ;)

Comment: **Serial downvoting reversed** for techie007 an hour ago, for the others yesterday around 10:30 pm.